# text search in mysql jdbc

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I need to search throw a text field in mysql from my java application.  Should I use a search engine like Lucene?  Ideally it should support sql syntax.  
I need to search through the text field  quickly (eg. select * from mytable where textField like '%searchfor%' limit 100;)  
secondly,  if I need to wildcard search through all rows in the database, would using a search engine be much faster than performing like? 
what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a search engine on top of db is much faster since it uses its own index for text search.